# Response code causes issue parsing JSON Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to parse a JSON response in flutter but, there is a random "200," in the file and I'm not sure how to parse around it. I need the data from "rate_response", how do I get to it?

The response:

```
[
    200,
    {
        "rate_response": {
            "rates": [
                {
                    "rate_id": "se-449314776",
                    "rate_type": "shipment",
                    "carrier_id": "se-496556",
                    "shipping_amount": {
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "amount": 0.51
                    },
                    "insurance_amount": {
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "amount": 0.0
                    },
                    "confirmation_amount": {
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "amount": 0.0
                    },
                    "other_amount": {
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "amount": 0.0
                    },
                    "zone": 2,
                    "package_type": "letter",
                    "delivery_days": 2,
                    "guaranteed_service": false,
                 
                },
                {
                    "rate_id": "se-449314777",
                    "rate_type": "shipment",
                    "carrier_id": "se-496556",
                    "shipping_amount": {
                        "currency": "usd",
                        "amount": 1.0
                    },
            
                
            ],
     
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `parsedJson` is your whole value, then `parsedJson[1]` is your map that has a single key `rate_response`, so `parsedJson[1]['rate_response']` would be your map with a single key of `rates`, and `parsedJson[1]['rate_response']['rates']` would be a two element list of a couple of maps in a list, so `parsedJson[1]['rate_response']['rates'][0]` and `parsedJson[1]['rate_response']['rates'][1]` would access those maps, and so on.  It's straightforward to map the layout of most JSON to the Dart tree of Lists and Maps.  The really hard part is when the values vary within a level, because then you're stuck with a lot of `is` to work out which `dynamic` this is.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have get the `response` from your endpoint, new you have to do is get the data you want from your response.

You could try like this example bellow.

```
final response = await http.get("YOUR URL");
var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
var rateList = decodedResponse[0]['rate_response']['rates'];
print(rateList.toString());
```

Comment: I wouldn't call anything that is no longer JSON with a name that has "json" in it.  It gets confusing to read.

Comment: i updated my code snippet now you can read.... :) @RandalSchwartz